# SQL SELECT REQUEST ON DATE(String) and IdPatient(Integer)

Tags: sql

For a medical application, I search to be able to register a new appointment between a patient and his physician from a click on a calendar gridview cell and after display the appointment on the calendar with an indicator.

Now, I have a SQL `Select` statement which is supposed to get data from a table `Events` in the database on date and `idpatient` parameter like this :

```
String query1 = 
      "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS + "WHERE" + COLUMN_DATE_EVENTS + "=" + date + 
      " AND" + COLUMN_ID_PATIENT + "= " + idPatient;
```

Parameters `date` and `idPatient` are passed as arguments of the function and seems effectively to be received.

My date field is defined as a string in my database.

When I insert the event with the function saveEvent before that, 
the function

```
long result = database.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, contentValues)
```

returns "6.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I tried to get datas several times, but my cursor.getCount() is always to 0, so thinking it was maybe because there is a problem in saveEvent function, I "Log.d" display the result of my db.insert function and the result being not -1, I think it would have been inserted. My question is could it have a syntax problem in my request who does datas are not obtained from database ?

Comment: Can I effectively use an "=" symbol on a string date or is is illegal ?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: That's the request I use to create my table Event. Could it be there is a problem private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID_EVENTS + "INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + COLUMN_DATE_EVENTS + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + COLUMN_MONTH_EVENTS + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + COLUMN_YEAR_EVENTS + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + COLUMN_ID_PATIENT + "INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + COLUMN_ID_MEDECIN + "INTEGER NOT NULL " + ")";

Comment: When I display my sql request in the console with a Log.d, I obtain this result :    SELECT * FROM  events WHERE date LIKE 2020-04-23 AND patient_id = 2. So the date and id parameter seems to effectively not be the problem.

Comment: I tried to take off the "date" parameter of my request and just make that :           SELECT * FROM  events WHERE patient_id = 2. When I did that, my cursor.getCount() seems effectively get datas : I obtain "8" lines,                             but I would like get just datas from some dates.

Comment: parametrized queries ? Okay, I will already watch that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use.

I click on a gridView cell who opens a AlertDialog who shows name and firstname of the patient and the date and when I click one more time on the button in AlertDialog,
my function saveEvent register date as a string in database in this format :

2020-04-22

My function readEventsByIdPatient must after that get datas to display on the selected date the patient have a meet with his physician this day.
In the two Lod.d lines, I can see in the console my parameters date and idPatient are effectively get in the function.

public void readEventsByIdPatient(String date, int idPatient, SQLiteDatabase database) {

```
    Log.d("readEventsByDate", String.valueOf(date));
    Log.d("readEventsByIdPatient", String.valueOf(idPatient));

    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS + "WHERE" + COLUMN_DATE_EVENTS + "=" + date + "AND" + COLUMN_ID_PATIENT + idPatient;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query1, new String[] { date },null);

    Log.d("cursorGetCount", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

           do {

                String Date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
                String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("month"));
                String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("year"));
                int IdPatient = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("patient_id"));
                int IdMedecin = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("medecin_id"));

                Log.d("date", String.valueOf(Date));
                Log.d("month", String.valueOf(month));
                Log.d("year", String.valueOf(year));
                Log.d("IdPatient", String.valueOf(IdPatient));
                Log.d("IdMedecin", String.valueOf(IdMedecin));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the disturbance.

I hadn't seen before my last post, but in putting date parameter in this way, 
instead directly in the query, it seems to work.

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query1, new String[] { date },null);

Thank you still for your answers.